# How to target 100 specific cities that I provide a service to, requiring product installation and not harm SEO?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-places

The business provides custom hand carved limestone products, that are delivered and installed by us. The problem is this, the cities we target are in patches and spread over a 200 mile distance. Google listings won't cover that properly, even if I were to enter all zip codes manually.

I prefer content over a general listing that won't favor our business once out of a 30 mile service area. I believe a similar local business, if one exists, will rank better on Google Places and rightfully so.

I do not want to add all the cities, in a footer or anything silly like that plus I believe that is considered content farming / keyword stuffing …

My concern is that the main body content does not need to change, only the city names do, in which all meta info will be based on that city and change as well along with references to the city in the main content (make sense?).

With that, is it ok to create a page for each city and call it good or will it be flagged or poorly ranked as duplicate content? Or am I missing something much better that is being overlooked?

Answer (score 4):

Google views duplicate pages for each city as low quality "doorway" pages.   It gives it as en example directly in their webmaster guidelines: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en

You can have a page for each city but you have to make it unique and usable.   It can't just have a single action such as "Click here to go to our home page" or "click here to contact us".

To make it higher quality and acceptable to Google you can add:

- Delivery or travel charges specific for that city
- Prices specific to that city
- Turn around time that may be specific to that city
- A map of your location relative to that city
- Stats about how often you serve the city
- Reviews or testimonials from users in that city

The reviews and testimonials is probably the easiest way to get a large amount unique and relevant content onto the page.

Comment: Very good points made! Though I never had a problem yet, I wanted to get some extra scenarios, if you will and you brought up some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Schema.org is perfect for this.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressLocality": "Mexico Beach",
    "addressRegion": "FL",
    "streetAddress": "3102 Highway 98"
  },
  "description": "Need carved limestone? We got em",
  "name": "carved limestone Inc",
  "telephone": "850-648-4200",
  "areaServed": ["New York", "Florida", "Manhatten"]
}
</script>
```

https://schema.org/LocalBusiness

Validate using https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/

Markup everything as good good as you can. Perferrable by using a specific buisness instead of "LocalBusiness".
If you have more than one physical store, use several addresses instead of areaServed for those cities.

Place the code anywhere you want in your domain.com document. In head, body or even outside of html.

Comment: I like both answers. I like the diversity and uniqueness both of you have brought up and how they can be used together. Thumbs up to both!